# Existential quantifier in clausal form

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

How do I handle existential quantifier $\exists$  while converting predicate logic to clausal form?

For example, how do I write this is clausal form:

$$\exists x \operatorname {food}(x)\to \operatorname{likes}(x)$$

Which means there exist a food which John likes.

My try is this:

```
food(x)^~likes(John,x)
```

Please tell me if it is right or not. If it is not, how to write it correctly. Also please tell me what would have happened if there was a universial quantifier in place of ∃.

Thank You!

Comment: Your translation of the statement is incomplete. For example, if there exists anything that isn't food, the implication "food($x$)$\rightarrow$likes(John,$x$)" is true.

Comment: $$\exists x\big(\text{food}(x) \land \text{likes}(\text{John}, x)\big)$$

Comment: I removed them. Prior to your comment.

Comment: @amWhy But I think we need to remove all quantifiers after converting it to clausal form.

Comment: My comment is that what you wrote at the top is incorrect.  the existential statement is not a conditional.

Comment: Too bad.  Think about it.  You're a bit too rude, when all I did was tried to help you.

Comment: Sorry If I sounded rude. I acknowledge your help. Actaully I have a test going on right now. That is why I am in a bit hurry. Sorry again.

Comment: $\lnot \text {food}(a) \lor \text {likes}(\text {John},a)$